# Given $a,b,c$ belongs to $R^{+}$, prove that $(a^2+1)(b^2+1)(c^2+1) \geq 8abc$

Tags: inequality

Question:

> Given $a,b,c$ belongs to $R^{+}$, prove that $(a^2+1)(b^2+1)(c^2+1) \geq 8abc$.

How should I go about solving this?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Note the inequality is also obviously true if $abc\lt 0$ and hence for all real numbers $a, b, c$

Answer (score 4):

**hint**: $a^2 + 1 -2a = (a-1)^2 \geq 0$

Answer (score 2):

$$a>0 ,b>0 ,c>0 \\ $$we know $$a+\frac{1}{a}≥2\\ b+\frac{1}{b}≥2\\c+\frac{1}{c}≥2\\$$ multiply them
$$ (a+\frac{1}{a})( b+\frac{1}{b})(c+\frac{1}{c})≥2\times2\times2\\$$ now multiply by a,b,c
$$ abc(a+\frac{1}{a})( b+\frac{1}{b})(c+\frac{1}{c})≥2\times2\times2abc\\$$

Comment: if a,b,c=0 it is trivial